Finding kernel of a set of polynomial functions
I have a list of polynomials fi[x_] and polynomial fractions qi[x_] (with i as an iterator) which are functions of several variables: x1, x2, x3, etc. I was trying to find linear combinations of these functions that go to zero. I multiplied them by constants and added them Sum[ci fi[x_] + di qi[x_]] (with i as an iterator) and found a long expression.
I used Collect function of Mathematica to collect terms with xi and tried to make the coefficients zero using Solve (I know now that that was a wrong approach to this problem). Is there a way to find these linear combinations of these polynomials that go to zero?

Are there relations between  qi[x_] and fi[x_]?

@user64494 yes, some parts of them are alike. They are linear combinations of some other polynomials.

Please have a look at SolveAlways. It is for exactly your problem.

Since your question lacks concrete example, I cannot judge my answer is really effective or not, but the following heuristics is very often useful.
Consider the cases where variables x1,x2,x3, ... take random integer values. Then each instance gives you a linear equation on the unknown multiplier variables ci and di. If you have enough number of such equations (and if you are lucky), you may find out the correct value of ci and di.
